# How do I fix a compiler error on Remix?

Tags: solidity

I have a compiler error and I don't understand how I can fix it. Please explain. Thank you!

[image]

https://photos.app.goo.gl/H1oS7YtjcTJtBKJv6

Comment: Hi drekerm! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! Please, include the code as text, that way it is easier to test. Use a better title and describe the error in detail.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `ok` from line 2 in your code, also consider removing one of your `//SPDX-License-Identifier:` lines as well since you have two of them.

[image]

For future reference, the little red box on Remix with an exclamation mark inside of it shows you which line the issue is coming from.